# How do I change the path that is being searched for launching an application?

Tags: terminal, bash, path

I am trying to launch the D programming language compiler DMD, but the terminal is giving the following error:

```
dmd: failed to launch executable at /Library/Compilers/dmd2/osx/bin/dmd
```

But there's not folder called `dmd2` under `/Library/Compilers`.

I can launch the dmd compiler from this path `/usr/bin/dmd`, but I don't want to type this path every time I need to compile a source code file.

This is my `$PATH`:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

Is there a way that when I type `dmd` it launches `/usr/bin/dmd`, instead of trying to language a compiler under `/Library/Compilers/dmd2/osx/bin/dmd`?

Comment: What's Your output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: How did you install dmd (and also note that it is not good to install into /usr/bin )

Comment: What does `type -p dmd` show? This is the dmd you are actually running

Comment: re the install we do need to know where it was installed from so we can see the documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21674/).

Comment: Put `/usr(bin` towards the front of the PATH. The path is searched from left to right, until a suitable executable is found.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, your PATH has to be modified to:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

so that your shell will find
    `/usr/bin/dmd`
before any other one called from within one of the 2 `Python` library directories.

Please note: it is a dangerous practice to let any software not distributed by Apple to install anything within `/usr/bin` (or `/bin`, `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`). This is a technic used by crapware to hide themself.

Comment: My 2nd § is inspired from @Mark 1st comment :).

Answer (score 0):

If `/usr/bin/dmd` works and your path has `/usr/bin` in it, and your path is exported, then you can just type `dmd`. Otherwise you can change your path like this:

```
echo "export PATH=\"/usr/bin:$PATH\"" >> .profile
```

after which every new terminal will have the path you want.
(this is the method used by homebrew, macports, etc)

Comment: make sure your PATH is exported for it to work.

Answer (score -1):

if the only thing you need to call is dmd, how about putting an alias in your ~/.profile?

add this to .profile:

```
alias dmd='/usr/bin/dmd'
```

then open a new terminal, or type **source ~/.profile** to relaunch .profile.

You can also type the alias command directly in the terminal and test it out first.  But it will not be around next time unless you put it in ~/.profile.

I do this quite a bit.  Don't like to mess with the PATH for every single app that needs bash launches and it avoids stepping on something else by mistake.

Then you just type:

**dmd ...your arguments...**

essentially, alias here does exactly what you don't want to do, it types out /usr/bin/dmd.